# Is there any program that can add titlebar functionality to the menubar panel?

Tags: menu-bar, window-manager

Looking to reproduce the Unity/Gnome3 (Linux desktops) feature set on a Mac:

specifically:

- adding various window management buttons to the menu bar panel (close, maximize, maybe tile left/right)
- drag from the top to drag a maximized window, just as you would drag from the top in Windows. On Gnome desktop you can just drag from the top to move a maximized window, even though there is a panel at the top of the screen just like on Mac. Really good use of Fitts law.
- double-click on empty space in the menubar panel to maximize/unmaximize a window.

Are the any ready-made solutions to this? Are these features actually possible to implement on Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Most of what you're asking is already there...

- The top of every window has Close, Minimise to Dock & Fullscreen buttons.
  [image]
  Alt/click the fullscreen button will maximise instead.
  Click & hold the fullscreen button then drag to the left or right of the screen will enable Split Screen.

  Additional features can be added to the title bar - right click to Customise
  [image]
- You can resize any window except fullscreen by dragging any edge or any corner.

  From edges...
  Alt/drag will resize from 2 sides.
  Shift/drag will resize from 3 sides.
  Alt/Shift/drag will resize from all 4 sides.

  From corners...
  Alt/drag will resize by mirroring the faces.
  Shift/drag will resize from one corner, preserving aspect ratio.
  Alt/Shift/drag will resize from all 4 corners, preserving aspect ratio.

  Cmd/drag will allow you to resize without bringing the window to the front.
  Adding any of the other modifiers will do as above, without bringing it to the front.
- Double click to maximise/minimise is an option in System Prefs > Dock
  [image]

Comment: No, I mean the menubar panel at the very top of the screen, not the title bar. The motivation is fitts law. i want to interact with the titlebar and window buttons from the very top of the screen. crick in topmost left corner of sceen to close, swipe from menubar panel to drag a maximized window out of position, etc.

Comment: Then no. The Menu bar doesn't 'belong' to any window, it belongs to the App.